# linq update not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have tried a lot but all in vain.
I have written a LINQ code but not able to save changes in database.
It is giving no error neither it is updating record.

```
class Program
{
    [Table(Name = "mainframe_replication")]
    public class mainframe_replication
    {
        private string _REPL_GUID;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_REPL_GUID")]
        public string REPL_GUID
        {
            get { return this._REPL_GUID; }
            set { this._REPL_GUID = value; }
        }

        private string _REPL_TYPE;
        [Column(Storage = "_REPL_TYPE")]
        public string REPL_TYPE
        {
            get { return this._REPL_TYPE; }
            set { this._REPL_TYPE = value; }
        }

        private string _RPT_ID;
        [Column(Storage = "_RPT_ID")]
        public string RPT_ID
        {
            get { return this._RPT_ID; }
            set { this._RPT_ID = value; }
        }

        private string _RPT_VERS;
        [Column(Storage = "_RPT_VERS")]
        public string RPT_VERS
        {
            get { return this._RPT_VERS; }
            set { this._RPT_VERS = value; }
        }

        private string _RPT_BYTES;
        [Column(Storage = "_RPT_BYTES")]
        public string RPT_BYTES
        {
            get { return this._RPT_BYTES; }
            set { this._RPT_BYTES = value; }
        }

        private string _REPL_DTM;
        [Column(Storage = "_REPL_DTM")]
        public string REPL_DTM
        {
            get { return this._REPL_DTM; }
            set { this._REPL_DTM = value; }
        }

        private string _NOTIF_ID;
        [Column(Storage = "_NOTIF_ID")]
        public string NOTIF_ID
        {
            get { return this._NOTIF_ID; }
            set { this._NOTIF_ID = value; }
        }
    }

    public class MyPoco
    {
        public string ReportId { get; set; }
        public string Reportversion { get; set; }
        public string ReportBytes { get; set; }
        public string ReportDate { get; set; }
        public string NotifId { get; set; }
        public string RecipAdd { get; set; }
    }

    public static string loglocation;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                Table<NOTIF_RECIP> NOTIF_RECIP_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_RECIP>();
                Table<NOTIF_SCHED> NOTIF_SCHED_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_SCHED>();
                Table<mainframe_replication> mainframe_replication_alias = db.GetTable<mainframe_replication>();

                var ids = NOTIF_SCHED_alias.Select(x => x.NOTIF_RPT_ID).ToArray();

                foreach (string notif_sched_data in ids)
                {
                    var repljoinmf = mainframe_replication_alias
                        .Join(NOTIF_RECIP_alias, mfr => mfr.RPT_ID, nr => nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ID, (mfr, nr)
                            => new MyPoco { ReportId = mfr.RPT_ID, Reportversion = mfr.RPT_VERS, ReportBytes = mfr.RPT_BYTES.ToString(), ReportDate = mfr.REPL_DTM.ToString(), NotifId = mfr.NOTIF_ID, RecipAdd = nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ADDR });

                    foreach (var repljoinmf_data in repljoinmf)
                    {
                        repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "abc";

                        //DO STUFF 
                        //  repljoinmf_data.NotifId = "Changedxyz";
                    }
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It is not giving any error while submitting changes.
What I need to change?
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: You should really only show small snippet of code, this is just too much.

Comment: Actually I thought that first comment of people will be about missing primary key,so ai added the whole code to show that i have Primary key here.Thanks for suggestion,I will remove unwanted code.

Comment: You are creating a `MyPoco` instance which has nothing to do with your database - if you want to update the database you need to work with the entity types, not other types _projected_ from the data.

Comment: Some formatting suggestions:  One line break (if any) is enough, and is't much easier to read if you line up code in the same execution scope vertically (don't indent too much)

Comment: @DStanley -Sure,i will keep in mind about the indentaion but yet I got no idea What shoyuld I do to make update .Some more clarification will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save your changes back to the original data source, you need to be working with the actual entities instead of *projections* of those entities.  Since you are joining two tables, one option is to put those instances into an anonymous type and update them:

```
foreach (string notif_sched_data in ids)
{
    var repljoinmf = mainframe_replication_alias
        .Join(NOTIF_RECIP_alias, 
              mfr => mfr.RPT_ID, 
              nr => nr.NOTIF_RECIP_ID, 
              (mfr, nr) => new {mfr, nr});

    foreach (var repljoinmf_data in repljoinmf)
    {
        //DO STUFF 
        repljoinmf_data.mfr.NotifId = "Changedxyz";
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

In your previous question you were told that anonymous types cannot be uptated, but in this case you're modifying instances that are *referenced* by the anonymous type.  So you're not updating the anonymous type *itself*, just the objects that the anonymous type references.

Comment: You are genious.thanks a lot Sir.i dont know why I was using projections.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the property of your `MyPoco` object. This is just a representation of your table. That's why the database is not updated.

You can send your MyPoco to your client. It will perform some changes. Then you can recreate the entity and copy the properties from the Poco object. Then, you need to [attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978(v=vs.110).aspx) the modified entity to your table and then save the changes.

If you modify directly the entity, there is no need to attach, since it will have kept the links to the database (assuming you do that with the same Databasecontext).

Comment: Any suggestion what should I change .?

Comment: For each entity you want to to an update (and obviously before submitting your changes), you have to tell Entity Framework the entity was updated. Unless you have specified otherwise (I assume not), EF won't pay attention to these entities. So follow the article Kryptos has provided and you should be fine.

Comment: @hbulens The OP is not using EF but System.Data.Linq (i.e. LinqToSQL). Anyway the concepts are the same indeed.